# Best way to aggregate information from multiple machines

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

I am trying to improve a windows service we use at work.

The part I am trying to improve is the maintainability. The service exists on several different machines. Now, I have a form which receives information from the service via Shared Memory, but to monitor these services someone has to login to several remote machines to view the forms.

What I am trying to do is decide the best way to have these services send their information to a single location for easy viewing.

My initial thought was to create a web service which the services could call with their details. Then create a web page where those details could be viewed. But I imagine that I will also need a db to store the messages in which I don't really want to have to do.

I would also like for the location in which shows the combined details to be able to send commands to the individual services, such as Start and Stop.

So I am lacking a bit of knowledge on the best way to accomplish this and am looking for suggestions that would give me something more specific to research.

I would appreciate any and all input on a real-time appropriate solution to having multiple window services located on several different machines within our network to send their status data to a single location to be displayed visually together, as well as allowing that form/website/whatever to send messages to those services such as Start and Stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the Web Service/SQL approach, WCF might be a good approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

Basically the remote services could report to the central service, and everything could be stored in memory, no DB required.